# Reading Danish characters from text files

Tags: c#

I am trying to read text files that contains some danish characters. I have found a few ways to do it using different types of encoding but the examples I have seen are reading just one file. This is what I have so far.

```
//search directory for all .txt files
foreach (string files in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\ftp\inbox", "*.txt"))
{     
    //The 'using' command close connection when it is done
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(files)))               
    {
        // Handle contents
    }
}
```

My problem is all the characters are being read as �. I need them to be read in as they are.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My problem is all the characters are being read as �. I need them to be read in as they are. Thank you for any input.

Comment: I resolved the issue by changing
using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(files)))
to
using (var reader = new StreamReader(files, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))) 

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: @robertwoods: please add an answer with your solution and then mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(files)))
```

into

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(files, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
```

and now the danish characters are read in as they should be.

Comment: Saved my day :). utf-8 did not work and could not find the correct encoding before i saw this. Thanks