# Change encoding to UTF8 for data kept in base64string

Tags: c#, parsing, encoding

I need to process CSV files that are kept as bsae64strings. I never know in what format they were created (usually it'll be ANSI or UTF-8). I have been struggling to achieve anything useful, still, I receive messed up characters when I am testing my code on CSV file that was saved in ANSI. The code to read is just a two-liner:

```
byte[] dataToDecode = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Content); 
string csvContentInUTF8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataToDecode2);
```

I do not have access to the code that saves files.

Sample line that's in the input CSV:

;;;superÆ/æ Ø/ø and even Å/å Topic;;John;Doe;;;;john@doe.com;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

what I get after decoding (second line of code)

;;;super�/� �/� oraz �/� Topic;;John;Doe;;;;john@doe.com;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027758/reading-danish-characters-from-text-files) I tried changing the code to scandinavian encoding reading, so:

```
string csvContentInUTF8x = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(dataToDecode);
```

The output is:

;;;superï¿½/ï¿½ ï¿½/ï¿½ oraz ï¿½/ï¿½ Topic;;John;Doe;;;;john@doe.com;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

It looks exactly the same for the Encoding.Default

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including an example base64 string and the CSV content you expect as the output from that base64 string.

Comment: UTF8 and Base64 are completely different things. One is used to encode text. The other for binary data. `CSV` files are *never* binary so checking for BASE64 is meaningless

Comment: As for ANSI or UTF8, there won't be any difference - ANSI refers to the 7-bit subset that is *identical* in UTF8. If you get mixed up characters it's because the text was saved using a different codepage.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos For ansi codepage in windows it means "any old-style codepage" (see for example https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2006/09/29/list-of-ansi-code-pages-used-by-windows/) and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#The_code_page_numbering_system), *Microsoft defined a number of code pages known as the ANSI code pages (as the first one, 1252 was based on an apocryphal ANSI draft of what became ISO 8859-1)*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No. It matters. `è` is perfectly defined in Windows-1252, that is called "ansi codepage", and is > 127. Its encoding is different between W1252 and UTF-8.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The wrong sentence was *ANSI refers to the 7-bit subset that is identical in UTF8*. You exchanged ANSI for ASCII. ASCII refers to the 7-bit subset that is identical in UTF8

Comment: @xanatos actually, I think I'll delete all the (essentially) unrelated comments before they result in downvotes to the question

Comment: @cAMPy what you posted doesn't show anything related to BASE64 **or UTF8**. It shows text that was read using the *wrong* codepage. **UTF8** uses *two or more* bytes for anything outside the 7-bit range. You'd never see `Æ/æ Ø/ø`, you'd see NULL characters followed by other characters

Comment: "I never know in what format they were created" is a problem if you literally mean the encoding could vary between different files, and the files don't come with a BOM to indicate they're UTF-8, as there's no reliable way to detect the encoding in that case.

Comment: What should be the expected result? I can't infer what the Æ/æ, Ø/ø, Å/å should be

Comment: @xanatos the "Æ/æ Ø/ø  Å/å " are scandinavian characters that I expect to have in the output.

Comment: Since you have base64 strings I'd guess these are email attachments? If you're lucky then there might be a content encoding attribute on the content-type.

Comment: @cAMPy you have ASCII text encoded with some unknown codepage. If there are no NULL characters it's *definitely* not UTF8. If you don't know what the codepage is you'll have to guess. Try reading/decoding it with *all* available codepages and discard anything that contains `�`, that's essentially the conversion error character

Comment: @cAMPy what does the *input* look like? What happens if you use `Encoding.Default` or `Encoding.GetEncoding()` with a Scandinavian codepage?

Answer (score 0):

If what you wrote is correct, the text was corrupted *before* writing it in a csv file.

Now... `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` is an identical encoding that doesn't do any remapping. Its 256 characters are mapped 1:1 to the first 256 (0-255) characters of unicode.

```
;;;superï¿½/ï¿½ ï¿½/ï¿½ oraz ï¿½/ï¿½ Topic;;John;Doe;;;;john@doe.com
```

You see the `ï¿½` repeated six times? Normally each time it should be different, because you want six different characters (Æ/æ, Ø/ø, Å/å). But here they are always the same. And this is because in UTF-8 `ï¿½` is the Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER `�` that is used when a character can't be encoded. So the error is already present in your `dataToDecode`.